# Find top surface of solid object in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a binary segmentation of a solid object in a Matlab 3D array called `mask` (`1000x1000x1000 uint16`). I need to extract the top surface, i.e., the first non-zero element for each column vector (over the second and third dimensions). I can do this with the following code snippet:

```
s = zeros(1000,1000); 
for y=1:1000
    for x=1:1000
        s(x,y) = find(mask(:,x,y),1);
    end 
end
```

Is there a way to vectorize the code and avoid the `for` loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the indices of the [maximum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) value (one in your case). [Squeeze](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) these indices to remove singleton dimensions and convert into the desired form (`s`).

```
[~, ind] = max(mask); 
s = squeeze(ind);
```